# How to replace all occurrences of "00000" with "0" repeatedly?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, binary

I need to repeatedly replace all occurrence of `00000` with `0` in a binary string input.

Although I'm able to achieve it to some extent, I do not know the logic when there are multiple consecutive 00000s like **for example**:

- 25 0s should be replaced with one 0
- 50 0s should be replaced with two 0s
- 125 0s should be replaced with one 0

Currently I have following code :

```s
new_list = []
c = 0
l = list(s.split("00000"))
print(l)
for i in l:
    if i == "00000":
        for x in range(l.index(i),l.index(i-3)):
            if l[x] != 0:
                break
        for y in range(0,5):
            del l[i-y]
    new_list.append(i)
    new_list.append("0")
r_list = new_list[0:-1]
r_list= ''.join(map(str, r_list))
print(r_list)
```

But this will not work for 25 0s.
Also What would be the regex alternative for this ?

Comment: Why is it that 25 `0`s get replaced by 1 `0`, 50 `0`s get replaced by 2 `0`s, and 125 `0`s get replaced by 1 `0`? What's the underlying logic here? Can you explain it in words?

Comment: If you don't know the underlying logic, then where does this task come from? Is there some kind of program whose behavior you're trying to replicate?

Comment: My best guess at what you're trying to do is that you're trying to **repeatedly** apply the rule that 5`0`'s get replaced with 1, so that 25 `0`'s get reduced to `00000`, which in turn gets reduced to `0`. Is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, basically the output string should not contain {00000} , that means every five constitutive 0s must be replaced by {1}

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. That said, the whole point of confusion here is that "output string should not contain {00000} " and "every five constitutive 0s must be replaced by {1}" mean two different things

Comment: I understand it [like this limited try](https://regex101.com/r/6J5uLr/1) wondering how/if that could be done with a recursive regex (e.g. using PyPI regex).

Comment: @mac Please check if my edit of your question is alright. Besides changes to title and formatting, I also changed the word "constitutive" to "consecutive", hope that is correct.

Comment: If "every five consecutie 0's must be replaced by {1}", that contradicts the rule that 25 0's must be replaced by 0.   25 0's must be replaced by 11111, right? You have to work out the exact set of rules, and in what priority they are applied when more than one rule can apply, and whether there is a process of repeated rule application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those results, you would need to *repeatedly* replace five consecutive zeroes to one zero, until there is no more occurrence of five consecutive zeroes. Here is an example run:

```
s = "0" * 125  # example input
while "00000" in s:
    s = s.replace("00000", "0")
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I state in my comment, my best guess at what you're trying to do is that you're trying to repeatedly apply the rule that 5`0`'s get replaced with 1, so that, for example, 25 `0`'s get reduced to `00000`, which in turn gets reduced to `0`. Assuming that's correct:

It's not the most efficient approach, but here's one way to do it:

```
import re

new = "00000100002000003000000004" + "0"*50
old = ""

while old != new:
    old,new = new,re.sub("0{5}","0",new)
print(new)                              #0100002030000400
```

Alternatively, here's a method to apply that change in one pass through the array:

```
s = "00000100002000003000000004" + "0"*50

stack,ct = ['#'],[-1]
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == stack[-1]:
        ct[-1] += 1
        i+=1
    elif ct[-1] >= 5:
        q,r = divmod(ct[-1],5)
        ct[-1] = q+r
    else:
        stack.append(s[i])
        ct.append(1)
        i+=1
while ct[-1] >= 5:
    q,r = divmod(ct[-1],5)
    ct[-1] = q+r

ans = "".join(c*k for c,k in zip(stack[1:],ct[1:]))
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

[PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) supports [recursion](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html). Something like this could do:

```
import regex as re

s = re.sub(r"0000(?:(?0)|0)", "0", s)
```

See [this Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21QiGxGMjg4iouKSpWsFWIVjIAASUdCI3JQQP45HBriuXiSssvUihWyMxTAFlsxaWgALK9KFWvuDRJowhspoa9lYa9gWaNgaaSjoIS0CaFYk2guoKizLwSjWLN//8B) or the [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SBEJnH/4)
At `(?0)` or alternatively `(?R)` the pattern gets pasted (recursed).